# JOINTSWP How to turn on foundation prototype breakpoints in JOINTWSP

Tags: zurb-foundation

Best place to ask is foundation forum but their server returns errors.

Hopefully someone from JointsWP will find this.  They say to tag with "JointsWP" but impossible to create a new tag.

I need to turn on Foundation Prototype Breakpoints.  I managed to include the Foundation prototype classes by including in the Styles.scss file, but the breakpoints are not included.

I have tried:
Including all three of these settings in _settings.scss:

```
`$prototype: true;`
`$global-prototype-breakpoints: true;`
`$prototype-transformation-breakpoints: true;`
```

I have tried downloading various custom downloads of Foundation to see if I can figure out which files to load.

I have searched through the Foundation node modules to see if anything is not being loaded but no luck.

I can create my own classes using the mixins, but it seems there should be a simple way to include the classes already created with Foundation.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "Hopefully someone from JointsWP" not automatically. You can ping / write them. Also ZURB Foundation has Gitter and Slack channels too.

Comment: Not sure but has JointsWP a Sass / SCSS compiler running in the background?

Comment: JointsWP says to use 1) Their own forum which was throwing an error or 2) Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, we are using a SASS compiler but I have no problem have my scss compiled.  It just appears that they didn't include all of the Foundation classes, and though I've been able to add other classes on my own, this one was beyond me.   I ended up writing my own mixins.